# SQL Duplicate Values Issue on LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, outer-join

I am trying to do a Join within 4 tables but it is returning duplicate rows. Some Items might not exist on Sales and Inventory tables. What needs to be done to resolve the issue;

ProductList (We need all the items)

Item_ID

ProductDetail (it has the return all the matching items from Product List)

```
Item_ID
Product_Name
```

Sales (needs to return all matching items from ProductList)

```
Item_ID
Sales_Qty
```

Inventory

```
Item_ID
Remaining_Qty
```

SAMPLE DATA

ProductList

```
Item_Id
--------
0001
0002
0003
0004
```

ProductDetail

```
Item_Id   Product_Name
-----------------------
0001      Eraser
0002      Pencil
0003      Pen
0004      Mouse
0005      Keyboard
0006      Monitor
0007      Cable
```

Sales

```
Item_ID   Sales_Qty
--------------------
0001      15
0002      20
0004      50
0005      60
0006      45
```

Inventory

```
Item_ID   Remaining
-------------------
0001      100
0002      95
0003      55
0005      101
0006      13
0007      18
```

Desired output:

```
Item_Id    Item_Name   Sales_Qty    Remaining_Qty
--------------------------------------------------
0001      Eraser          15           100
0002      Pencil          20            95
0003      Pen             0             55
0004      Mouse           50            0
```

My query :

```
SELECT *
FROM ProductList a 
INNER JOIN ProductDetail b ON a.Item_ID = b.ItemID 
LEFT JOIN Sales c ON a.Item_Id = c.Item_ID 
LEFT JOIN Inventory d ON a.Item_ID = d.Item_ID
```

Comment: If you're getting duplicates, it's because the `Item_ID` appears more than once in one or more of the joined tables. You need to consider how you want to resolve these duplicates? Take the first row, sum the values, average the values, etc. Or if they are truly duplicate values, you can use `SELECT DISTINCT...`

Comment: If you want return all Sales matching to ProductList why are you using LEFT JOIN? Also could you provide sample data and expected output? Thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: "duplicate rows" is vague & you don't say how output is a fucntion of input & you don't give an example, so how can we help? Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Comment: I have added sample data.. Maybe it is not just the duplicate issue.

Comment: You haven't actually done what my comment said. We can't cut & paste & run that. Etc. PS The main problem here is that your expectations of left join are not how it actually works. We can't address that until you tell us what those are. Tell us the first subexpression of the logical evaluation order that doesn't return what you expect & why. PS When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. PS Google 'stackexchange notifications' re using @ to notify a user of a comment.

Comment: wjat is your expected output? If I understand your post correctly, you are expecting 3 records with Item_Id equal to 0001, 0002, 0004. If not, please update your post with expect result. Thanks

Comment: @sam I am trying to show All the items in the productList ( 001, 002, 003, 004 ) and their corresponding values from other tables. If there is no matching data in other tables, return Null or 0.

Comment: @AAA then you need to use left join for all the tables.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DISTINCT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Item_ID, * 
FROM ProductList a 
    INNER JOIN ProductDetail b 
        ON a.Item_ID = b.ItemID 
    LEFT JOIN Sales c 
        ON a.Item_Id = c.Item_ID 
    LEFT JOIN Inventory d 
        ON a.Item_ID = d.Item_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
SELECT a.Item_Id, b.product_Name, c.Sales_Qty, d.Remaining_Qty
    FROM      ProductList a 
    LEFT JOIN ProductDetail b      
              ON a.Item_ID = b.Item_ID 
    LEFT JOIN Sales c              
              ON a.Item_Id = c.Item_ID 
    LEFT JOIN Inventory d          
              ON a.Item_ID = d.Item_ID
```

This will produce this output:

```
Item_Id     product_Name    Sales_Qty   Remaining_Qty
---------------------------------------------------
  0001          Eraser        15          100
  0002          Pencil        20           95
  0003          Pen          NULL          55
  0004          Mouse         50         NULL
```

If you don't want nulls to be returned, then use COALESCE (if your database is sql server, you can use ISNULL instead of COALESCE) as shown below:

```
SELECT a.Item_Id, b.product_Name, COALESCE(c.Sales_Qty, 0), COALESCE(d.Remaining_Qty, 0)
    FROM      ProductList a 
    LEFT JOIN ProductDetail b     
              ON a.Item_ID = b.Item_ID 
    LEFT JOIN Sales c             
              ON a.Item_Id = c.Item_ID 
    LEFT JOIN Inventory d         
              ON a.Item_ID = d.Item_ID
```

This will produce this output:

```
Item_Id    Item_Name     Sales_Qty    Remaining_Qty
--------------------------------------------------
 0001         Eraser          15           100
 0002         Pencil          20            95
 0003         Pen             0             55
 0004         Mouse           50            0
```